# Evidence for $\epsilon_{0}$ and $\mu_{0}$ being invariant between different inertial frames

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, speed-of-light, physical-constants

Are $\epsilon_{0}$ (permittivity) and $\mu_{0}$ (permeability)  invariant between different inertial frames? If yes, what hard evidence does it support that? If no, why would $c$ (velocity of light) be invariant between different inertial frames and what is the need for Lorentz transformation?

Answer (score 2):

To add to [C.R. Drost's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307182/26076): Given the *experimental fact* of the invariance of Maxwell's equations, the invariance of $\mu_0$ arises by definition; it defines our unit of current. An intuitive and covariant form of Maxwell's equations is:

$$\Box\,A^\alpha = \mu_0\,J^\alpha$$

where $A^\alpha$ is the (contravariant) four potential and $J^\alpha$ the four current.

You can see $\mu_0$ defines the relationship between our units for current and units for potential / EM field by telling us how much field we get for how much current. We *define* our units so that the ampere is the current that would, if present in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross section, and 1 meter apart in vacuum, give rise to a force between these conductors of $2\times10^{-7}{\rm N}$ per meter of length of conductor. This definition of the ampere fixes $\mu_0$ to its SI value of $4\pi\times10^{-7}{\rm H\,m^{-1}}$. Implicit in this definition is that this scaling is defined in a frame at rest relative to the conductors. Given the empirical fact of the covariance of Maxwell's equations, we are free to choose a frame that is convenient for measurement, just as we define the invariant mass of a particle through its total energy in a frame at rest to the particle.

The invariance of $\epsilon_0$ then of course follows from that of $c$ and that of $\mu_0$.

Comment: More generally it's $\nabla_\beta F^{\beta\alpha}=\mu_0 J^\alpha$, but in a flat spacetime that reduces to your given equation provided we work in the gauge $\nabla_\alpha A^\alpha=0$.

Comment: @J.G. Absolutely true: The question was about inertial frames and I  simply wanted a form that most evoked a "one way" (in the sense of RHS + boundary conditions fully define the LHS) current to implied solution relationship. One strictly gets that with the more general form, but the quoted form is a little more obvious IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic constant is fixed by our choice of SI units as $4\pi\cdot10^{-7} \text N/\text A^2.$

The electric constant could vary if $c$ varies and the hard evidence to suggest it doesn't is precisely the hard evidence that suggests a fixed $c$.